# define user based value to the firebase instance collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have two pages FirstPage and SecondPage. I am passing the argument or value from FirstPage to SecondPage. Is it possible in the SecondPage to get the value adjusted in the ("${widget.col}") ? I tried this way but could not get that value.

```
FirstPage

onTap : {

  Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(gen: 'collection')));}

SecondPage



    class SongProvider extends ChangeNotifier { 
    late final String col;
 SongProvider({required this.col}); 
final _worshipColleciton = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("$col");
```

Comment: Can you include your console data structure image

Answer (score 0):

To pass data you can do

```dart
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(collectionName:'collection')));}
```

Then in screen 2

```dart
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final String collectionName;

  SecondScreen({Key key, required this.collectionName}) : super(key: key);
}
```

If you notice collection name is the string required by screen 2 and that's being passed from screen 1

Comment: I want that value in the FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("${widget.col}");

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("${widget.collectionName}") if you use stateful widget. FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("${collectionName}") in case you are using stateless widget

Comment: class WorshipSongProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  late final  String col;

  WorshipSongProvider({required this.col});
  final _worshipColleciton =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("$col");